# How can I make find pass file names to exec without the leading directory name?

Tags: linux, find

Someone created directories with names like `source.c`. I am doing a `find` over all the directories in a tree. I *do* want `find` to search in the `source.c` directory, but I do *not* want `source.c` to be passed to the `grep` I am doing on what is found.

How can I make `find` not pass directory names to `grep`?  Here is what my command line looks like:

```
find sources* \( -name "*.h" -o -name "*.cpp" -o -name "*.c" \) -exec grep -Hi -e "ThingToFind" {} \;
```

Comment: The [tag:find] tag is fine for questions about the \*nix command line utility. See the [tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/find/info). You should *not* use the tag for questions about searching in general, e.g. "How can I find myself?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `-a -type f` to your `find` command. This will force `find` to only output files, not directories. (It will still search directories):

```
find sources* \( -name "*.h" -o -name "*.cpp" -o -name "*.c" \) -a -type f -exec grep -Hi -e "ThingToFind" {} \;
```